# How to hide content from Epub on Sigil

Tags: epub, sigil

I'm using Sigil 0.7.4 to make something like this Epub:

http://www.jw.org/download/?issue=201508&output=html&pub=km&fileformat=EPUB&alllangs=0&langwritten=E&txtCMSLang=T&isBible=0

It has endnotes and additional information. But notice that when you open it on a tablet with MoonReader, it hides the endnotes and additional information from the flow.

I tryed checking the Css and XHTML but it has nothing special. I don't know how they managed to do that.

Is there a way to hide the endnotes and additional information from the flow using Sigil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mobileread's user Doitsu:

> You can hide chapters from the flow by manually adding a linear="no" attribute in the spine section of the .opf file. However, many reading apps ignore this attribute.

To hide the endnotes:

Put this on the HTML tag:

```
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"
```

Put this on the a tag:

```
epub:type="noteref"
```

And finally use epub:type=footnote on the aside and div of the citation:

```
<aside epub:type="footnote">
    <div epub:type="footnote" id="citation1">
        <p><a href="#citation_ref1">^ <strong>[1]</strong></a>Citation</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```